# Problem authenticating Google GCP with Dockers

Tags: windows, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-authentication, google-cloud-sdk

I need to work on some previously pushed docker images stored on Google's gcr.io hubs.

I am doing this from a Windows 10 machine, with standard installations of Docker and Google Cloud SDK (no Homebrew or anything like that).

After setting permissions for my gmail account in GCP's IAM section, I am still getting this error message when using this in PowerShell:

```
docker pull gcr.io/blabla/blabla:latest
```

> Error response from daemon: unauthorized: You don't have the needed
>   permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid
>   credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in:
>   https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication

On going through setting up [authentication](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication) again, I get these error messages

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud auth configure-docker
>
> WARNING: `docker-credential-gcloud` not in system PATH. gcloud's
>   Docker credential helper can be configured but it will not work until
>   this is corrected.
>
> WARNING: `docker` not in system PATH. `docker` and
>   `docker-credential-gcloud` need to be in the same PATH in order to
>   work correctly together. gcloud's Docker credential helper can be
>   configured but it will not work until this is corrected.

On searching for solutions, I came across [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49780218/docker-credential-gcloud-not-in-system-path) which appears to use macOS commands. I've found the Windows alternative for 'which', which is 'where', giving this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>where gcloud
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\gcloud
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\gcloud.cmd
C:\Users\l.cai\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\gcloud
C:\Users\l.cai\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\gcloud.cmd
```

But I'm having a lot of trouble understanding [this post explaining the alternative for readlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298414/native-alternative-for-readlink-on-windows). Replacing parts of that syntax with the filepaths either give

> ' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command

or

> The system cannot find the path specified.

Multi-line commands also don't work well in Windows PowerShell or CMD, so I'm not sure where they're entering commands into.

Can anyone please help me along with this? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution: Log into Windows itself with an admin account. None of the other fixes/threads referred to in my OP ended up being relevant.

I had a local administrator account, but since this was set up recently, I was used to logging in to my usual work account (non-admin), and only entering the local admin credentials as needed (e.g. when running programs with elevated privileges).

So docker and powershell and cloud SDK can all be started individually with admin privileges, but somewhere along the chain it breaks, and I'm not prompted for anything. Logging in with the admin account circumvents that.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that neither `gcloud` nor `docker` is setup correctly for the user that you are logged in as. The following is a temporary solution. You should reinstall docker and the cloud SDK.

Verify that both components of the path below are correct and adjust for your installations.

Open a Windows Command Prompt and execute:

```
set PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;%PATH%
```

Comment: I've executed the command, but nothing seems to have changed. Same errors are returned. I've updated the OP with returns from 'where gcloud', if this changes anything. Also, what should I do differently when reinstalling docker and cloud SDK? Both were fresh installs with standard options.

Comment: Type `docker --version`. What is the result?

Comment: Type `gcloud version`. What is the result?

Comment: docker: Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4 ========== gcloud: Google Cloud SDK 228.0.0 |
bq 2.0.39 |
core 2018.12.07 |
docker-credential-gcr |
gsutil 4.34 |

Comment: In your message you say that docker is not on the PATH, but you are able to execute it which means it is on the PATH.

Comment: Which version of Windows 10 - Home or Professional?